# Need max(id) by location but always getting the same value for each location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running a query in sqlserver where i need the latest id by location the location is in a different table but i can join on the id. The problem is the values are always the same and not for each location. Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(select max(id) from t
where p.partname = 'ibiza')locid,
p.partitionkey,
t.partitionkey,
p.partdesc,
p.partname
FROM
t1 t1,
t t
WHERE
t.partitionkey = t1.partitionkey
GROUP BY
t.id,
p.partitionkey,
p.partname,
p.partdesc,
```

t.partitionkey;

Comment: Post your table structure if you could.

Comment: I would recommend to use table names instead of table letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some issues besides your id problem:

1. Distinct is useless when you are already using group by.
2. Joins are easier to read (in my opinion) when actually using the "join" keyword
3. There is no join to "p" (I assume that's why you are mixing up group by and distinct - I am not able to fix that without the structure)
4. The group by t.id can be remove as it is already aggregated by the "max" function

However, the actual issue is, that you are always selecting the last ID as a column (for every row it is selecting the same value), that's why it is always the same - there is no reference to the actual row.

This would be better (at least I guess - without the table structure):

```
SELECT max(t.id) as locid, p.partitionkey, t.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname 
FROM t join p
on t.partitionkey = p.partitionkey
where p.partname = 'ibiza'
GROUP BY p.partitionkey, p.partname, p.partdesc, t.partitionkey
```

**Edit:**

Now I think I understand, there is no t1! It should be p?

Again, please use table names!